# Xamarin Forms Device.Styles FontFamily

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, label

I am trying to use Xamarin's built in Device.Style's for setting the font size of a Label; however, once I apply the style the custom font family I set is being overridden. I am using "Device.Style" because I want to adhere to the users Accessibility settings. How can I use the Device.Style's but use the font family in the global style? On some cases I am using the style over 40+ times, so I don't want to place it on the label itself.

**Global Style**

```
 public static Style TitleLabelStyle {
        get {
            return new Style(typeof(Label))
            {
                BaseResourceKey = Device.Styles.TitleStyleKey,
                Setters =
                {
                    new Setter { Property = Label.TextColorProperty, Value = BasicStyle.PrimaryColor },
                    new Setter { Property = Label.FontAttributesProperty, Value = FontAttributes.Bold },
                    new Setter { Property = Label.FontFamilyProperty, Value = Device.OnPlatform("cubano", "cubano.ttf#cubano", "cubano") }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: @SushiHangover that's not at all what I'm looking for. This is C# Xamarin Forms PCL.

Comment: I'm following what you're saying about setting the font size. The font sizes work perfect using Xamarins Device.Styles; however, the style is overriding my custom fontfamily. The multiplier table does not help or address this issue. I want to use the tools that Xamarin has put in place but am having an issue trying to set the fontfamily, not with the fonts not scaling appropriately.